# How do i access a key from my azure keyvault in Azure ad b2c custom IEF policy?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an API subscription key which is used to access API. I need to provide the subscription key in header. I  have stored the subscription key in Key Vault and need to access it in my custom policy IEF azure ad b2c. It is important to note that i need to pass subscription key in api header

I tried the policy keys options under custom policy and provided a reference to it under cryptography tag. however i am not really sure the use of cryptography tag to store keys

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there.
You need to create a policy key as mentioned in below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/policy-keys-overview?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#policy-key-management
Please ensure you are using key type "Manual"

[image]

Once key is added then

just create a new rest api technical profile and use your key in CryptographicKeys section

here is an example which passes keys in header

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-Sample">
      <DisplayName>ShowErrorMessage</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ApiKeyHeader</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
        <!--EnvSpecifc-->
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://sampel.api/endpoint</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <!-- in  below line x-functions-key is header name-->   
        <Key Id="x-functions-key" StorageReferenceId="Key-name-created-inside-b2c" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Above example should be enough for you do what you need. For more details please refer below link which explain how can you pass parameters to api from B2C.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#metadata

I don't think you need to read this key from KeyVault, it would make your solution unnecessary complicated, keeping this secret/key inside policy key should make it safe.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. can you please also tell me if I use bearer authentication . how will i handle expiration token?